# Enum as Class Property

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, enums

I have a class for something simple, Status, and it contains two properties.  I want to use an Enum for one of the Properties(StatusID) so that I can eliminate a bunch of Magic Strings.

My question is how I then work with it, for example: I have a Method that returns a List for binding in a dropdown box that looks like this -->

```
public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses()
{
  IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
       .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
       .Select(s => new Status()
       {
         StatusID=s.StatusID,
         StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
       });
   return stat.ToList();
}
```

It obviously does not like my `StatusID=s.StatusID` part as the DB stores it as a varchar.  Am I missing something simple here or have I stumbled into noob territory and should not be doing it this way?

For reference here is the Class and Enum:

```
public class Status
{
  public string StatusID {get; set;}
  public string StatusDescription {get; set;}
}

public enum MyStatusID
{
  draft, pending, declined, accepted, close 
}
```

---

EDIT

So taking the advice here I was able to get my method to compile however at runtime I get the following --> `Method 'System.Object Parse(System.Type, System.String)' has no supported translation to SQL.`

Thoughts?

---

EDIT - Method in it's entirety by request, thanks (NOTE that NoaStatusID == MyStatusID)

```
   public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses(NoaStatusID currentStatus = NoaStatusID.draft)
    {
        using (var context = MemberDataContext.Create())
        {
            IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
                   .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
                   .Select(s => new Status()
                     {
                       StatusID=NoaStatusID)Enum.Parse(typeof(NoaStatusID),s.StatusID),
                       StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
                     });

            switch (currentStatus)
            {
                case NoaStatusID.draft:
                    stat=stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.draft || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.pending));                                                     
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.pending:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.accepted || s.StatusID ==NoaStatusID.declined || s.StatusID ==NoaStatusID.pending));
                    break;                        
                case NoaStatusID.declined:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.draft || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.pending || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.declined));
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.accepted:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.mailed || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.monitor || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.accepted));
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.mailed:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.mailed || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.monitor || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.appeal));
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.monitor:
                case NoaStatusID.appeal:
                case NoaStatusID.close:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.appeal));   
                    break;                    
            }


            return stat.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where are you using the `MyStatusID` enum? Isn't your `StatusID` property still a string?

Comment: I want to Replace the `string StatusId` with `enum MyStatusID` so to keep my Magic Strings in one spot.  The values of the enum match the possible DB choices for StatusID.

Comment: Do you want a descriptive text or are you fine with the string representation of the enum value? despite all of that, the DB choice for StatusID **should be** an int. varchar and int are perfectly interchangable, you could store a converted int value for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i believe what you're searching for is:

```
StatusID = (MyStatusID)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyStatusID), s.StatusID),
```

in .Net 4.0 there is also a `Enum.TryParse(string, out enum)` but that is not so useful inside your `.Select()`

**Alternatively:**
albeit less efficient in most cases, you can keep the `Status.StatusID` as a string and add a readonly property `StatusEnum` that outputs the Enum value on the fly:

```
public MyStatusID StatusEnum {
    get {
        return (MyStatusID)Enum.Parse(typeof(MyStatusID), StatusID)
    }

    private set;
}

in .Net 4.0:
public MyStatusID StatusEnum {
    get {
        MyStatusID value;
        if(!Enum.TryParse(StatusID, out value)
          value = MyStatusID.Default; // default value, instead of Exception throwing

        return value;
    }

    private set;
}
```

this alternative re-parses the value everytime instance.StatusEnum is read, so I don't recommend it unless LINQ hates the first approach

---

Responding to your last EDIT:

The Enum.Parse() is translating to SQL fine in your example. The problem is in the switch statement where you're adding on a `.Where()` clause that has a comparison with an `Enum`. LINQ doesn't know how to turn an `Enum == Enum` into SQL but it **does** know to do it with C# objects. So the easiest solution is to ToList() them and do the comparison locally. Unfortunately, that means it's downloading rows of -all- Status types from the database and then filters them locally. If you have millions of records this may not be reasonable:

```
   public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses(NoaStatusID currentStatus = NoaStatusID.draft)
    {
        using (var context = MemberDataContext.Create())
        {
            List<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
                   .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
                   .Select(s => new Status()
                     {
                       StatusID=NoaStatusID)Enum.Parse(typeof(NoaStatusID),s.StatusID),
                       StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
                     })
                   .ToList();

            switch (currentStatus)
            {
                case NoaStatusID.draft:
                    stat=stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.draft || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.pending)).ToList();                                                     
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.pending:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.accepted || s.StatusID ==NoaStatusID.declined || s.StatusID ==NoaStatusID.pending)).ToList();
                    break;                        
                case NoaStatusID.declined:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.draft || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.pending || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.declined)).ToList();
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.accepted:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.mailed || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.monitor || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.accepted)).ToList();
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.mailed:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.mailed || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.monitor || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.appeal)).ToList();
                    break;
                case NoaStatusID.monitor:
                case NoaStatusID.appeal:
                case NoaStatusID.close:
                    stat = stat.Where(s => (s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.close || s.StatusID == NoaStatusID.appeal)).ToList();   
                    break;                    
            }


            return stat;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your first approach seems to work.  Thanks very much, I will see what I can do about getting that column switched to an int but I am glad to have found a way to make it work anyway.

Comment: See my Edit, does this mean I have to use your 2nd approach?

Comment: can you post your code under the edit. I just attempted it myself locally and do not get the System.NotSupportedException exception - works fine for me. Using .Net4.0

Answer (score 1):

Isn't [what](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) you are looking for?

```
 Colors colorValue = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorString);
```

Comment: If I would have been paying attention this is works as well and is the same as a couple of the other answers.  THanks

Answer (score 0):

If you make the backing field* an `int`, it will work just fine.

In fact you can even use `byte` enums (with a `smallint` backing field).

There is a problem with the designer however. IIRC, the `enum` declaration needs to be in the same namespace.

Note: By backing field, I mean the database table column type.

Comment: what if the enum is literally a string representation of what I want.  e.g. MyStatusID.draft == "draft" or are you saying I'd be better off switching my DB ID column to `int` then in this instance?

Comment: That will not work AFAIK. Is there any reason why it should not be a 'normalized' item?

Comment: sorry for the denseness but how do you mean 'normalized'?  With an `int` backing it or some other way?

Comment: Normalized as in SQL terms, `TABLE Status (Id int PK, Name varchar(max))`.

Comment: I can look into it.  It may be possible, I don't control DB setup so...:)

Comment: i agree with leppie, ideally your database column should be an int foreign keyed to a StatusType table. It makes indexing and querying faster and saves space. But not always possible for legacy and in-production systems

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is that you want the `String` equivalent of the enum value, but it isn't very clear:

```
public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses()
{
  IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
       .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
       .Select(s => new Status()
       {
         StatusID=Enum.GetName(typeof(MyStatusID),s.StatusID),
         StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
       });
}
```

EDIT: Given the comments, sounds like you want:

```
public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses()
{
  IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
       .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
       .Select(s => new Status()
       {
         StatusID=(MyStatusID)s.StatusID,
         StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
       });
}
```

EDIT: Given the (further) comments, sounds like you want:

```
public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses()
{
  IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
       .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
       .Select(s => new Status()
       {
         // If database is storing 'draft' (as a varchar)
         StatusID=Enum.Parse(typeof(MyStatusID), s.StatusID),
         StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
       });
}
```

Or maybe

```
public static IList<Status> GetAdminStatuses()
{
  IQueryable<Status> stat=context.tblAdminStatus
       .Where(s => s.InactiveDate > DateTime.Now || s.InactiveDate == null)
       .Select(s => new Status()
       {
         // If database is storing '0' (as a varchar)
         StatusID=(MyStatusID)int.Parse(s.StatusID),
         StatusDescription=s.StatusDesc
       });
}
```

Comment: And this will not blow up under LINQ2SQL?

Comment: Eh, yeah probably would.  Interesting to try though.

Comment: It is interesting but for me error stating `an instance of string cannot be assigned to a member of type MyStatusID`

Comment: Did you change the signature of the `StatusID` property on the class `Status`?  Your question shows it as a `String`.

Comment: Yeah I did, I was trying to show how it was before I changed it.

Comment: Can you cast a string to an enum?

Comment: @comecme I am guessing s.StatusID is an int.

Comment: I don't think so. OP wants to replace `string StatusID` by `MyStatusID StatusID`. He also states the database stores the statusid as varchar.

Comment: despite all that is possible, s.StatusID **should be** an int!

Comment: your third of four answers is the correct one (as it is a copy of my already supplied answer). However i believe it would need a `(MyStatusID)` casting because `Enum.Parse` should just return an `Object` type