# How do I set available options for a property?

Tags: c#

I want to do something similiar to FormStartPosition where intellisense give you options when you hit the dot after the property. How do I do that?

Comment: That behavior is automatic for enums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean is called enum, here's an example:

```
public enum Staff
{
    Alice,
    Bob,
    Chris,
    Diana
}
```

Comment: How would that implementation look like when you want to use it as a property?

Comment: A quick search gave me this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11440410/enum-as-class-property